# Редактор кода Vim не видит Python

Tags: python, vim

Python для vim потребовался после установки плагина YouCompleteMe. Скомпилировать плагин, вроде получилось (Python рабочий, консоль Cmder Bash). Но каждый раз при запуске даёт ошибку:

> **YouCompleteMe unavailable: unable to load Python.**

По команде **:py pass**, ошибка:

> **E370:** Невозможно загрузить библиотеку msys-python2.7.dll
>
> **E263:** К сожалению эта команда не работает, поскольку не загружена библиотека Python

1. Устанавливал разные версии Python 2-3 x86 и x64;
2. Нагуглил что нужно задать, в vimrc, путь для файла dll python38.dll (этот хотя бы существует на компе)... В отличие от msys-python2.7.dll (этого вообще нет нигде — прикол требовать файл, который не устанавливается с питоном);

Проблема ни у меня одного (еле нагуглил иностранные источники с плохим переводом), но так не решена! Информации почти нет, на русском - нет вообще! Уже неделю решаю!

Comment: Месье знает толк... Вам нужен питон под msys.

Comment: по этому не надо использовать vim..

Comment: @finally поэтому не стоит юзать `windows`. Ну или понимать, что ты используешь, а не имееть сразу несколько компиляторов, IDE и версий библиотек под каждую в куче и обращаться с ними все так же как с кучой.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch тоже верно, но `vim` все же ужас.. но и переход на другую ось потребует времени

Comment: @finally никакой это не ужас - я им пользуюсь уже почти 2 года и (особенно сравнивая с колегами на работе, который пользуются IDE) абсолютно даволен. Вряд ли хоть что-нибудь может обеспечить столь быструю работу (особенно когда освоить `w3m` или что-типо того). Я уже не говорю о независимости от IDE (когда спрашиваешь у коллеги: а с какими флагами ты хоть компилирушь? - а в ответ: ну я просто сдесь кнопочку нажимаю...)